# I want to convert a column into a string

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have an image like below.

[image: Image Example]

I want to save each line of this column as an element of array.

I wrote statements a Datatable in C#.

```
con.Open();
string sql = "SELECT MA_BO_CAU_HOI FROM R_NGUOICHOI_BOCAUHOI where MA_NGUOI_CHOI="+ cbbten.SelectedIndex +"";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataTable data = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(data);              
int[] number = (int[]) data.Columns[0];     
con.Close();
```

But It's not working. How can I do it
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I am just not able to see correlation between your subject and your code. You have said you want to convert to a string but you have coded for an integer array.

Comment: In another way, you no need to see my code. I just want to ask. How can I save each line of this column (in the picture) into array?

Comment: we do need your code if you want help, and the subject and code look very different to each other. flagged to close as it is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

Use loop.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
   list.Add(int.Parse(row["ColumnName"]);
}

int[] number = list.ToArray();
```

Also if you aware of `LINQ`, you can do it on one pass:

```
int[] number = tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => int.Parse(x["YourColumnName"].ToString())).ToArray();
```

EDIT: After the comment about the data

Use `CommandParameters` to fetch data from DB. It will protect you from sql injection. Also try to wrap your Connection(I don't see where is defined) in using block too.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your conn"))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT MA_BO_CAU_HOI FROM R_NGUOICHOI_BOCAUHOI where MA_NGUOI_CHOI=@Param1";

    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", cbbten.SelectedIndex);
         adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

         adapter.Fill(data);         
    }
}
```

Comment: although your answer will work for the user, I think they are having trouble actually getting the data, ive upvoted your answer anway as it is technically correct based on subject

Comment: @SimonPrice I fixed his code about fetching the data too.

Comment: I like the touch of LINQ, I guess if I were in a happier mood today I would have probably helped as you have :)